# How to select distinct with linq when comparing values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to do a select distinct where I compare 2 values. In the method I do the following:

```
DistinctErrors = Errors.Select(o => new { o.Type, o.References })
                       .Distinct()
                       .Count();
```

o.Type is a string, but o.References is a Collection of objects. Each object in o.References has a Name property as string and a Value Property as string, and it's actually o.Type and each o.Reference's Name and Value values I want to compare, so it's actually 3 values to compare.

How can I compare Type with each Reference Name and Value?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: So you want the number of items in `Errors` that have a distinct `Type` and a distinct collection of `References`?  Or do you want the number of distinct references in `Errors` by `Type`, `Name`, and `Value`?  An example would help here.

Comment: Override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in the type you are working. Distinct will see the content of these methods to execute.

Comment: Alternative to the @FelipeOriani way for comparison is to provide distinct with IEqualityComparer, that is more useful if there are multiple versions of comparison algorithms. In both cases, it has advantage, that it simplifies the code: Errors.Distinct().Count();
or
Errors.Distinct(instance IEqualityComparer).Count();

Comment: Perhaps the best thing you can do is to provide us with an algorithm, a simple method, that compares two objects in Errors...
bool Compare(Error a, Error b) { ... }
From there we can manage to help you:).

Comment: #juharr Errors is an ObservableCollection<T> where each item contains several properties. One of the properties is Type, that is a string. Another one is References, that is an IEnumerable<T>. Each Reference item has 2 properties, string Name and string Value. For each Error item the properties Type, References.Name and References.Value can be the same/appear several times. DistinctErrors is just a number saying how many distinct errors I have in my Errors Collection, i.e.how many unique errors I have. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to flatten the references using `SelectMany`?

```
DistinctErrors = Errors.SelectMany(o => o.References, (o, r) => new {o.Type, r.Name, r.Value})
                       .Distinct()
                       .Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem since I only get to the Collection References, and not to each item in References, which means I don't find r.Name and r.Value.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it properly?   I created a sample structure (class with a References collection property) and it worked for me.  Can you add the types of `Errors` and `References` to your question?

Comment: With the risc of portraying myself as a complete idiot...my mistake was that References is/was an IEnumerable<object>, so of course it didn't work. I changed that and now of course it's working. Thanks a lot for the help!! :)

Comment: @PeterCentellini OK That explains why it wasn't working - glad you figured it out.